# Converting integer and calculate mean in R but still does not work

Tags: r, integer

I have a integer variable. Normally after I convert to numeric I can calculate mean of this. BUt this time I convert using this code but still doesn't work. 
Does anyone know what's the problem? Thanks

Example of the value of variable NPVC_m1 is like this:

```
771]  52524847.0  52524847.0  52524847.0  52524847.0  52524847.0  52524847.0  52524847.0  52524847.0  52524847.0  52524847.0

 [781]  70026530.6  70026530.6  70026530.6  70026530.6  70026530.6  70026530.6  70026530.6  70026530.6  70026530.6  70026530.6

 [791]  87524914.7  87524914.7  87524914.7  87524914.7  87524914.7  87524914.7  87524914.7  87524914.7  87524914.7  87524914.7

 [801]  46418440.1  46418440.1  46418440.1  46418440.1  46418440.1  46418440.1  46418440.1  46418440.1  46418440.1  46418440.1

 [811]  92833975.5  92833975.5  92833975.5  92833975.5  92833975.5  92833975.5  92833975.5  92833975.5  92833975.5  92833975.5

 [821] 139000000.0 139000000.0 139000000.0 139000000.0 139000000.0 139000000.0 139000000.0 139000000.0 139000000.0 139000000.0

 [831] 186000000.0 186000000.0 186000000.0 186000000.0 186000000.0 186000000.0 186000000.0 186000000.0 186000000.0 186000000.0

 [841] 232000000.0 232000000.0 232000000.0

typeof(NPVC_m1)

[1] "integer"

> NPVC_m1 <- as.numeric(as.character(NPVC_m1))

> typeof(NPVC_m1)

[1] "double"

> meanNPV <- aggregate(NPVC_m1 ~ Region + Model, subsetfinal, mean)


Warning messages:

1: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

2: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

3: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Comment: Please use `dput(head(df,10))` to provide sample data and make the post more readable.

Comment: You need to convert it inside `subsetfinal`. (Well, what you really should do is fix your data import so the conversion is not necessary.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought after attach data I could do it without put subsetfinal at the beginning. It works! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand how the numbers you show in your question can be integers:

```
> x <- c(52524847.0, 52524847.0, 52524847.0, 52524847.0, 52524847.0, 52524847.0,
+        52524847.0, 52524847.0, 52524847.0, 52524847.0, 70026530.6, 70026530.6,
+        70026530.6, 70026530.6, 70026530.6, 70026530.6, 70026530.6, 70026530.6,
+        70026530.6, 70026530.6, 87524914.7, 87524914.7, 87524914.7, 87524914.7,
+        87524914.7, 87524914.7, 87524914.7, 87524914.7, 87524914.7, 87524914.7,
+        46418440.1, 46418440.1, 46418440.1, 46418440.1, 46418440.1, 46418440.1,
+        46418440.1, 46418440.1, 46418440.1, 46418440.1, 92833975.5, 92833975.5,
+        92833975.5, 92833975.5, 92833975.5, 92833975.5, 92833975.5, 92833975.5,
+        92833975.5, 92833975.5, 139000000.0, 139000000.0, 139000000.0,
+        139000000.0, 139000000.0, 139000000.0, 139000000.0, 139000000.0,
+        139000000.0, 139000000.0, 186000000.0, 186000000.0, 186000000.0,
+        186000000.0, 186000000.0, 186000000.0, 186000000.0, 186000000.0,
+        186000000.0, 186000000.0,  232000000.0, 232000000.0, 232000000.0)
> as.integer(x)
 [1]  52524847  52524847  52524847  52524847  52524847  52524847  52524847  52524847
 [9]  52524847  52524847  70026530  70026530  70026530  70026530  70026530  70026530
[17]  70026530  70026530  70026530  70026530  87524914  87524914  87524914  87524914
[25]  87524914  87524914  87524914  87524914  87524914  87524914  46418440  46418440
[33]  46418440  46418440  46418440  46418440  46418440  46418440  46418440  46418440
[41]  92833975  92833975  92833975  92833975  92833975  92833975  92833975  92833975
[49]  92833975  92833975 139000000 139000000 139000000 139000000 139000000 139000000
[57] 139000000 139000000 139000000 139000000 186000000 186000000 186000000 186000000
[65] 186000000 186000000 186000000 186000000 186000000 186000000 232000000 232000000
[73] 232000000
```

As you can see, coercing your numbers to integers **truncates the decimal places**.

Please note that `as.integer()` does *not* round the number:

```
> 70026530.6
[1] 70026531
> as.integer(70026530.6)
[1] 70026530
> options(digits=10)  # to force display of decimal places
> 70026530.6
[1] 70026530.6
> as.integer(70026530.6)
[1] 70026530
```

Also, I can quite easily calculate the mean of integers:

```
>     x <- c(4, 5, 6, 6)
>     typeof(x)
[1] "double"
>     x <- as.integer(x)
>     typeof(x)
[1] "integer"
>     mean(x)
[1] 5.25
```

I can also `aggregate()` the means:

```
> subsetfinal <- data.frame(NPVC_m1 = x,
                            Region = rep(c("A", "B"), c(36, 37)),
                            Model = c(rep(c("one", "two", "three"), 24), "one"))

> aggregate(NPVC_m1 ~ Region + Model, subsetfinal, mean)
  Region Model      NPVC_m1
1      A   one  64632550.34
2      B   one 135718369.75
3      A three  67549222.65
4      B three 139243363.88
5      A   two  66091023.98
6      B   two 135396195.18
```

Therefore the problem you have must be unrelated to the type or class of the numbers that you show in your question.

Please create sample data that allows us to reproduce your problem and include it in your question.

---

`typeof(NPVC_m1)` returns `"integer"` or `"double"`. But **what does `class(subsetfinal$NPVC_m1)` return?** As @Roland noted (see the comments below), your variable might be a factor.

Comment: @Roland I don't understand what you mean with your comment.

Comment: It's an answer to the first sentence in your answer.

Comment: @Roland You are right, thank you. That would explain the error message. I changed my last sentence to reflect this.